# NextJS implementation of history replace

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-router

I have a ReactJS app that I am trying to replace with NextJS in a sample project.
In ReactJS, I had a **history.replace** functions that was used to navigate / push from current page to next based on auth.

Not sure how to implement the same in NextJS. Seems like using **useNavigate** combined with **router.push** may work but its giving me error.

**old code**

```
function handleRedirectToOrBack() {
    history.replace(location.state?.from ?? './profile');
  }
```

**new code** (not working)

```
function handleRedirectToOrBack() {
    router.push(location.state?.from ?? '/profile');
  }
```

The function does not take the user to "profile" after authentication. Just hands there.

Comment: How/where is `router` declared? What is the value of `location.state`?

Comment: Drew. Router is used in NextJS implementation. Location.state is current page.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] so it is clear what is declared and where, and so we've more complete context for what the code is trying to accomplish.